# PowerShell - how can I remove repeated backslashes in the string

Tags: powershell

```
$string = "my\\\name\\is\John\\\\Doe"
```

Desired output:
my\name\is\John\Doe

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets talk about what we need to do.

Take the string and create an array by using `-split '\\'`.
Why `\\` because `-split` allows for **regex** and `\` is an escape string for regex.

Next we need to remove all blank array objects by using `Where-Object` making sure the length of the string is greater then 0.

Lastly we use that with the string method `join(Joining Char, Array)`

The `join()` method allows you to join an array creating a string using a char as the glue.

```
$string = "my\\\name\\is\John\\\\Doe"
[string]::join('\',($string -split "\\" | Where-Object{$_.length -gt 0}))
```

returning

```
my\name\is\John\Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

Same principal, different methods

```
$string = "my\\\name\\is\John\\\\Doe"
$string.Split('\').where{$_} -join '\'
```

Output

```
my\name\is\John\Doe
```

Another way using regex

```
$string = "my\\\name\\is\John\\\\Doe"
while($string -match '\\\\'){$string = [regex]::Replace($string,'\\\\','\')}
```

Output

```
$string
my\name\is\John\Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `-replace` just seems simpler.

```
# replace all single or consecutive \ with a single \
$string -replace '\\+','\'

# replace each \ that had a preceding \
$string -replace '(?<=\\)\\'
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. I wish i could gift my answer to this.
Good regex skills @AdminOfThings